# Parse Pandas dataframe and calculate the mean

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm running simulations with 10 different seeds and my data is output in the following format:

```
Time        Node    SeqNo   Type        DelayS      RetxCount   HopCount
0.0070824   1       0       LastDelay   0.0070824   1           2
0.0070824   1       0       FullDelay   0.0070824   1           2
0.00708243  2       0       LastDelay   0.00708243  1           2
0.00708243  2       0       FullDelay   0.00708243  1           2
0.00708255  3       0       LastDelay   0.00708255  1           2
0.00708255  3       0       FullDelay   0.00708255  1           2
...
```

I'm using Pandas to parse the 10 different files into 10 separate "summary" files using these two lines:

```
df = pd.read_csv(appDelayFile + extension, delimiter="\t")
df = df.groupby(["Type", "Node"]).mean()
```

the output is (times 10 files):

```
Type    Node    Time            SeqNo           DelayS              RetxCount       HopCount
FullDelay   1   956.607342072   2581.91030329   0.574193060194      2.42267154227   6.77866207787
FullDelay   2   504.697133213   2462.08413511   0.316495995187      2.18526100307   4.18382804504
FullDelay   3   511.320534174   2523.32545343   0.402727314841      1.84043203587   4.70593030365
LastDelay   1   504.697133213   2462.08413511   0.0406310965189     1.0 4.18382804504
LastDelay   2   511.320534174   2523.32545343   0.0709971222702     1.0 4.70593030365
LastDelay   3   753.469111331   2527.55276175   0.0523313594699     1.0 8.14097279472
```

Questions:

1: How do I combine the 10 different files and calculate the average for each node?

2: I'm only interested in the FullDelay metric. Can I filter the output of Pandas to shown only FullDelay rows?

Thank you!

Comment: Select the rows with `df[df['Type']=='FullDelay']`. Combine the dataframes with `pd.concat()`. Read docs.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the one that worked for me was `df.ix['FullDelay']`